# How to access a website on a separate vlan (DMZ)

Tags: networking, website, internet-security

I have an Apache webserver (on Raspberry PI) running in my home environment.
This website is accessable from the Internet by port forwarding on my router.
The protect my LAN I have defined a separate vlan to create a dmz for the webserver.

`Reference: https://www.tp-link.com/nl/support/faq/788/`

By design devices on separate vlans cannot communicatie with each other.

What is a practical and secure method to manage the webserver from a PC on the LAN (on a different vlan)?

Comment: DMZ is to keep public traffic away from your LAN, not LAN traffic from DMZ device(s) typically... Your router should have a route statement to allow your LAN subnet to talk to your DMZ devices. And VLAN's are inherently segregated but in practice often communicate with each other via a router as the primary purpose of VLAN's is to segregate broadcast zones. But my question is, how are these connected and are they sharing the same router, if so what router is it?

Comment: In the reference I mentioned that my topology is conform example 1. So there is 1 subnet and 2 vlans. Computers in the two vlans cannot communicate with each other, but both of them can access the internet via the router. The router is a ZTE H369A owned by the ISP who has given me limited access, I cannot define a static route although I don't know if that would solf the access.

Comment: Is there another vlan definition possible so I have access from the LAN to the DMZ?

Comment: If your device is setup in a "DMZ" and both your LAN and DMZ device are connect to the same router and it is working properly, you should just be able to communicate with it from the LAN. Otherwise it is not a DMZ. If it is just two unique networks then you need to setup allow communication between the two networks with your firewall rules. If it is just two separate static networks, connect a second interface to the Pi and connect it to the "LAN". Otherwise I the answer already given is a legitimate one.

Comment: Because there is only one subnet I think youare not able to communicatie from the LAN to the DMZ via the router. Maybe it is possible to use an ad hoc wireless connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want separate lans for the risk that implie i suggest a vpn network to connect each other devices, then you could manage it, I'm not sure what are you using on the rasberry but here you can give you an very good idea
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Do you mean A VPN between two local computers or via the Internet. Is there no simple local solution?

Comment: Not a local solution, no. a local station on a VLAN can do absolutely nothing to affect accessibility of another vlan, except perhaps to make it dual-homed, with a nic connected to both VLANs. Hosts on VLANs talk to each other via a router.

Comment: The one has the dmz active set a vpn server and then any client it will connect via internet you will limited to the banwiht but it is a solution or of course you can connect them locally but for give you more ideas you should share a bit more info as how many interfaces has each computers or if they are wireless are free if it is the case connect each other wireless

Comment: i think you problem is more a bout firewall's another idea you can connect just anther router to your's isp router ones you have full acces there is easy get hands on one from a previus service etc... give a static ip to that router in that connect your local network and give dmz to your rasberry

Comment: I have a small environment. In the DMZ there is only the raspberrypi. In the LAN there are some computers, a printer and an wireless accesspoint for mobile phones. So a very small environment. If I need access to the raspberry i manually use temporary a different eth port on the switch. I dont like this. I hoped I could configure the port so that there is no access from the rasp in the dmz to the lan but there is access from a computer on the lan to the raspberry through a port with PVid 1 (default vlan) or something tike this.

Comment: Maybe an easy solution is to try a ad hoc wireless connection to the raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

From Paul Gorman from [https://paulgorman.org] I received a simple but briljant solution.
Just add a static route to the management PC to reach the raspberry pi in the DMZ via the router.

Comment: I ask myself that this is valid too from the DMZ, this should mean that a vlan is not secure.It is easy to communicatie between vlans via the router by defining a static router in your computer.
I realize now this is said by user acejavelin in the first answer.

Comment: It means at the router the firewall must prevent this and an extra router is needed when your ISP don't allow configuration of the firewall of the router. Bad news for me.
Paul Gormon tells me that a vlan is not a complete solution for security.